# retrieving value only show one data

Tags: javascript, php, html

in my from when i enter the category in the text box it will retrieve the subcategory but my problem is that only show one value of subcategory,because i use here text box.how can i show every data in list or something like
that on.please can any one help me?

my add_sales.php file

```html
<?php include_once("init.php");
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/auto/css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
 <?php include_once("tpl/common_js.php"); ?>  
        <script src="lib/auto/js/jquery.autocomplete.js "></script>  
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    
     $("#item").autocomplete("stock.php", {
  width: 160,
  autoFill: true,
  mustMatch: true,
  selectFirst: true
 });
        
$("#item").blur(function()
{    
$.post('check_item_details.php', {stock_name1: $(this).val() },
function(data){

$("#itemselect").val(data.itemselect); 

}, 'json');
});
 
 });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
   
<form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
<table class="form" >
<tr>
  <td>Item:</td>
 <td>product select</td> 
  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input name="item"  type="text" id="item"  maxlength="200"  class="round default-width-input " style="width: 150px"   /></td>
<td><input name="itemselect"  type="text" id="itemselect"  maxlength="200"  class="round default-width-input " style="width: 150px"/></td>                          

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my check_item_details.php file

```html
<?php
include_once("init.php");
 
$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.cat_id = subcategory.cat_id WHERE category ='".$_POST['stock_name1']."'");
$cname=$line->subcategory;

if($line!=NULL)
{
$arr = array ("itemselect"=>"$cname");
$arr1=
echo json_encode($arr);

}
else
{
$arr1 = array ("no"=>"no");
echo json_encode($arr1);

}
?>
```

Comment: Because you are using queryUniqueObject()

Comment: for that what i want to do,i new for this sir,thank you

Comment: use `query` instead of `queryUniqueObject`

Comment: function queryUniqueObject($query, $debug = -1)
    {
      $query = "$query LIMIT 1";

      $this->nbQueries++;
      $result = mysql_query($query) or $this->debugAndDie($query);

      $this->debug($debug, $query, $result);

      return mysql_fetch_object($result);
    }

Comment: how can i assign it query to show it